# Ansible - Find files via a list with their name and delete them

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

im currently running into an issue with deleting certain files from our thumbor cache with ansible. After alot of snipping I receive a list with the file names and im running following ansible task to find and delete them:

```
      shell: find . -name {{ item }} -exec rm "{}" \;
      args:
        chdir: "{{ thumbor_data_path }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      loop:
        - deletion_hash
      when: file_url is defined and deletion_hash | length > 0
```

the list is definitly filled with the correct names of files I know exist and the task itself marks himself as changed, but the files are not getting deleted. The names of the files are sha1 hashes, and are two directories deep.
Is there something wrong with the shell script?

Example of the deletion_hash list:

```
    "msg": [
        "115b744b9f6b23bbad3b6181c858cb953136", 
        "f52f17b2cca937e5586751ff2e938979890b", 
        "1c39661a0925b3cdb3b524983aaf6cccd6ee", 
        "1afc79a9e0e3c07ff0e95e1af3b5cb7ae54c", 
        "424e9159fe652f47c8e01d0aa85a86fbefed", 
        "11e4994789f24537d6feea085d2bf39c355b", 
        "a1d2fe0e122d37555df4062d4c0a5d10b651", 
        "aef976fc897a87091be5a8d5a11698e19591", 
        "e79f3ee1e6ccb3caff288b0028e031d75d77", 
        "9448e5e49679c908263922debdffff68eecb", 
        "a3933be52277a341906751c3da2dfb07ccd8", 
        "bef3370862a7504f7857be396d5a3139f5c0", 
        "8cc0cbe847234af96c0463d49c258c85d50f", 
        "1e7bf6110dcf994d1270682939e14416fc6e", 
        "d21dae2c047895129e7c462f6ddc4e512a58", 
        "c107b29b3185171ec46b479352fab6c97ad2"
    ]
```

Comment: Shell module in Ansible is always shown as changed, unless you ask it not to. Always avoid using this module, if there is another module helps your case, which is [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html). An example of the files list would be good to be able to help you.

Comment: @Khaled Yea i tried looking into the file module but I didnt see a good solution to make it loop with that list. It seemed to me that you can only place a single regex and im not sure if I could replace that regex with a loop iteration. I added an example list to the original post. The file names are basically hashes.

Comment: _but the files are not getting deleted_ : What is the error message you get from the `rm` command?

Comment: @user1934428 I get none whatsoever. Running this command on the same machine manually gives no errors either and the files are getting deleted. There is a slim chance though that thumbor recreates those files in a weird way right after them getting deleted. And if executed right, the rm command doesnt have an output, right?

Comment: Since `rm` always writes a message to stderr if it can't remove a file, so in your case this means that `rm` is never called, which in turn means that `find` does not produce any files, i.e. never executes anything. Hence the problem here is not why the files aren't deleted, but why `find` does not produce the list of files. I guess that if you replace `rm` by `echo`, you also don't get any output? BTW, when you use `rm` during debugging, do yourself at least a favour and add the `-v` option to it.

Comment: @user1934428 Alright, the -v option already cleared things up, totally forgot about that flag. Seems like the task is deleting the files, but Thumbor caches them again seconds after. Seems like I should have done more debugging. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The ansible way of doing this is using `file` module. However, you should do `loop: deletion_hash` (on the same line, without `-` ) assuming `deletion_hash` is already a list with file names marked for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `file` module; this comes with an assumption that the `thumbor_data_path` variable does not end with a `/`; if it does, you need to modify this a bit.

```
- name: Remove file (delete file)
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ thumbor_data_path }}/{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  loop: deletion_hash
  when: file_url is defined and deletion_hash | length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the code block. I included it in the playbook. Even though the code I posted original does seem to work, but thumbor just caches the files right after again, I prefer a "non shell rm" way of getting rid of those files! Just had to do some minor adjustments, since the first 4 letters of the hash create 2 directories and just [4:] is the file name.